# Is there any porous material that can have narrow parallel and "perfectly straight" cavities/holes through it (or bored through it)?

Tags: crystal-structure, materials, photochemistry, molecular-structure, nanotechnology

I'm basically looking for a material that can allow photons to pass through its cavities, but only those photons that travel at an angle (almost) exactly perpendicular to the materials surface. Non-perpendicular photons should be absorbed by the material upon impact as much as possible.

I can imagine perhaps a stack of graphene sheets, or a bunch of parallel carbon nanotubes? Or maybe a high precision laser drilling through ...something else? Clearly I'm no chemist or material scientist, so I'm hoping to tap into the knowledge of this community.

Comment: This is hardly chemistry. If your holes are small enough to be of interest to chemistry, then the photons don't pass through the holes. They pass through the material, if they can.

Comment: @IvanNeretin How large does a hole need to be for a photon to travel through it without being affected by the surrounding material? If this should be moved to physics.se, so be it. I posted this here, because I figured there was a strong material science aspect to this question...

Comment: I am not qualified to answer. Yes, I think the question belongs to physics.se.

Comment: Some microporous membrane filters might come close to what you are looking for. For example, see www.sterilitech.com.